# Global Variable and list assignment in R, getting unexpected result

Tags: r, list

I'm programming in R and I am placing lists inside lists. Consider the following vector:

```
> a = c(1,2,3)
> a
[1] 1 2 3
```

Then define a global list:

```
> foo <<- list()
> foo[[1]] <- a
> foo
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

and all is fine. Trying to modify this list inside a function/subroutine leads to

```
> foo <<- list()
> foo
list()
test <- function(){ foo[[1]] <- "a" }
> test()
> foo
list()
```

I'm finding that outside the subroutine that foo[[1]] is

```
> foo[[1]]
Error in foo[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Lets say however that I want foo to be global, then

```
> foo <<- list()
> foo[[1]] <<- a
Error in foo[[1]] <<- a : object 'foo' not found
```

gives a error - why? Additionally

```
> foo <<- list()
> foo
list()
test <- function(){ foo[[1]] <<- "a" }
> test()
> foo
list()
> foo[[1]]
Error in foo[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Finally trying

```
function(){ foo[[1]] <<-list(); foo[[1]] <<- "a" }
```

also doesn't result in anything fruitful. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, multiple issues. First, you don't need to use `<<-` except when inside a function. Just `<-` is fine at top level, and will do exactly the same thing. Your second error puzzles me, but you can fix it just by doing `foo[[1]] <- "a"`, with the non-global assignment. Your third code chunk is basically the same as the first - please edit your question. Your final try with the `function()` just makes no sense at all; you're assigning to the first element of `foo`, twice.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to make a list of lists, do `foo <- list(); foo[[1]] <- list(); foo[[1]][[1]] <- 'whatever'`. And don't mess with global variables in your functions. That leads to bad, hard-to-understand code. Instead, let each function take an input and return a result.

Comment: Let this serve as a gentle reminder that global variables aren't an ideal paradigm and that functional languages work best when functions don't have side-effects outside of their own scope.

Answer (score 4):

You make an understandible but important mistake: The `<<-` operator is used to assign something in the global environment from within a function, whereas you use it in the global environment.

To do what you want to do, try the following:

```
foo <- list()
myfun <- function(){
  foo[[1]] <<- 1
}
myfun()
foo
```

*edited per @MrFlicks comment:*

To be 100% correct, `<<-` actually looks for an object with the name `foo` in all parent environments. If it finds one, it will change that `foo` to the new value. If it doesn't, it assigns in the global environment. You can have more control over the exact environment where the assignment takes place by using the function `assign`, but with that one you can't set elements of a list. So the code would become:

```
foo <- list()
myfun <- function(){
  tmp <- get('foo',.GlobalEnv)
  tmp[[1]] <- 1
  assign("foo",tmp, .GlobalEnv)
}
myfun()
foo
```

Still, this is not a good idea in R.

#### Globals in R are not globals

R doesn't have "globals" that work the same as globals in eg Java. Actually, the entire idea of R goes against the logic of globals. So while you might think `<<-` defines a global, all it does is create an empty list in the global environment. But this is not what we understand under a global variable, because it can easily be deleted again from the global environment:

```
rm(foo)
myfun()
#> Error in foo[[1]] <<- 1 : object 'foo' not found
```

R functions are expected to have no side effects apart from a few obvious exceptions, so there are few mechanisms to actually define global variables.

#### How to do globals in R

If you really need a global variable that functions more like one would expect from a global, you can do a few different things. The best idea imho is using the options mechanism. R allows you to define your own option:

```
options(foo = list())
myfun <- function(){
  tmp <- getOption("foo")
  tmp[[1]] <- 1
  options(foo = tmp)
}
myfun()
getOption("foo")
```

To remove the option `foo`, just set it to `NULL`

```
options(foo = NULL)
```

On a sidenote: If you're developing a package, you can also define an object in the namespace of the package, just like you do with the functions. But I haven't found a good use case for this construct yet. My packages use the option mechanism, and that's what the user of a package will expect.

Comment: Actually `<<-` is used to assign to the parent or ancestor environment, not necessarily the global environment. Of course in many cases this just happens to be the global environment but that's not guaranteed. You can only safely assign to the global environment with `assign()`.

Comment: @MrFlick To be 100% correct, `<<-` searches through the parent environments to look for the variable with that name. And if it doesn't find one, it assigns to the global environment. So `assign()` is safer indeed, but `<<-` does assign in the global and not the parent when there is no variable with that name in any of the parent environments. See also `?"<<-"`. Also note that you have to specify the environment in `assign()` because that one assigns by default in current environment. And you can't assign to elements of a list using `assign`

Comment: Right. I think it would be safer to include that in the first paragraph rather than just say it always assigns to the global environment.

Comment: And right about the list elements. `assign()` should only be used with symbol names and `foo[[1]]` is actually a function call, not a variable name. You can use the ``` `[[<-`() ``` syntax to get a value you can use with `assign()` or do `evalq()` explicitly in the global environment. But I think we both agree that's it's just a bad idea to try to use "global variables" in R.