Problems storing authors when scraping Quotes To Scrape with RVest
I want to store authors from Quotes To Scrape in a list.
I have some functions to get quotes and authors, which are good: in the console, my scraping is perfect, and the script is finishing with a perfect list of quotes.
But my script can't store the authors, and my list of authors is empty.
Here is my functions (the script is very detailed because it is for a course):
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

start_url <- 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
start_page <- read_html(start_url)
session <- session(start_url)

get_quotes_elements <- function(page_url) {
  page <- read_html(page_url)
  quotes_elements <- html_nodes(page,".quote")
  return(quotes_elements)
}

get_quote <- function(quote_element) {
  quote <- list()
  quote_text = html_nodes(quote_element,'.text') %>% html_text()
  quote_author = html_nodes(quote_element,'.author') %>% html_text()
  quote_tags = html_nodes(quote_element,'.tags') %>% html_text()
  quote['Author'] <- quote_author
  quote['Quote'] <- quote_text
  quote['Tags'] <- quote_tags
  author_page_url <- paste0('https://quotes.toscrape.com', html_nodes(quote_element,"a[href*='/author/']") %>% html_attr("href"))
  author <- get_author(author_page_url)
  authors <- append(authors, author)
  print(paste(" Quote from ", author["Name"], " added"))
  return(quote)
}

get_quotes_pages <- function(start_url) {
  start_page_number <- 1
  pages_count <- 9
  quotes_pages <- list()
  quotes_pages <- append(quotes_pages, start_url)
  for (i in start_page_number:pages_count) {
    new_quotes_page_url <- quotes_pages[[i]]
    # print(paste("Processing ", new_quotes_page_url))
    new_quotes_page <- read_html(session %>% session_jump_to(new_quotes_page_url))
    next_quotes_page_url <- paste0('https://quotes.toscrape.com', new_quotes_page %>% html_nodes('li.next a') %>% html_attr("href"))
    # print(paste("next_quotes_page_url =  ", next_quotes_page_url))
    quotes_pages <- append(quotes_pages, next_quotes_page_url)
  }
  return(quotes_pages)
}

get_author <- function(author_page_url) {
  author <- list()
  first_author_page <- read_html(session %>% session_jump_to(author_page_url))
  author_name = html_nodes(first_author_page,'.author-title') %>% html_text()
  # print(paste("  Author name  ", author_name))
  author_born_date = html_nodes(first_author_page,'.author-born-date') %>% html_text()
  # print(paste("  Author born date  ", author_born_date))
  author_description = html_nodes(first_author_page,'.author-description') %>% html_text()
  # print(paste("  Author description  ", author_description))
  author['Name'] <- author_name
  author['BornDate'] <- author_born_date
  author['Description'] <- author_description
  return(author)
}

And I launch it with this script (I have limited the example to the first page of quotes):
quotes_pages <- get_quotes_pages(start_url)
first_quotes_page <- quotes_pages[[1]]
quotes <- list()
authors <- list()
for (quotes_page in first_quotes_page) {
  print(paste("Processing ", quotes_page))
  new_quotes <- list()
  new_quotes <- lapply(get_quotes_elements(quotes_page), get_quote)
  quotes <- append(quotes, new_quotes)
}

I was thinking that authors was declared as global variable, so the list authors can be filled with it, but apparently not.
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236620/global-variables-in-r (you need <<-  instead of <-)? There are few  R questions & answers that target quotes.toscrape.com , so perhaps you can get some inspiration (on how to avoid setting global variables in your functions ) - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+quotes.toscrape.com

No, unfortunately neither the <<- assignment nor the link you give me solves the problem.

Finally your answer drives me to the correct thing to do. First I did authors <<- list() but the result was the same. But I read this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120958/global-variable-and-list-assignment-in-r-getting-unexpected-result and it really helps me. The solution is to fill the list with <<- I write new script  in the answer below. Thanks !

Dear @margusl, I have another question (tell me if I have to open a new discussion). In my function get_author, I declare an author as a list, I add some attributes to the author, and finally I return author by doing return(author). So my result authors sould be a list of lists, with all authors as list. But in fact, authors is a list of characters. I found a workaround by doing return(list(author)) but I don't understand why I have to do so. Can you explain me why ? Many thanks !

This is expected behaviour of append(), you can play around with append(list(A = "a"), list(B = "c")) |> str() and append(list(list(A = "a")), list(list(B = "c"))) |> str() to check the difference.. BTW, you might want to be cautious with growing objects  (append() in a loop)  and setting global objects from functions ( any time you feel you need to use <<-) , those are circles 2 & 6 in [The R Inferno] (https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) .

Wow, what a strange behaviour. Ok, many thanks @margusl

Finally, as I said in comments, I changed my function get_quote to make a global append to the list authors, as this last is a gloabl variable. Here is the new code :
get_quote <- function(quote_element) {
  quote <- list()
  quote_text = html_nodes(quote_element,'.text') %>% html_text()
  quote_author = html_nodes(quote_element,'.author') %>% html_text()
  quote_tags = html_nodes(quote_element,'.tags') %>% html_text()
  quote['Author'] <- quote_author
  quote['Quote'] <- quote_text
  quote['Tags'] <- quote_tags
  author_page_url <- paste0('https://quotes.toscrape.com', html_nodes(quote_element,"a[href*='/author/']") %>% html_attr("href"))
  author <- get_author(author_page_url)
  authors <<- append(authors, author) # Here is the global assigment 
  print(paste(" Quote from ", author["Name"], " added"))
  return(quote)
}

